# what is a no-text[0-9] requests?

Tags: php, url, httpd

I have a bunch of requests coming through on my site which looks like the one below:

`example.com/page/no-text-1154169030774935240`

Is this hacking attempts or search engines?

EDIT: my question is regarding the request. The string at the end is used for an identifier which will load the appropriate page. Someone or something is passing the no-text-[0-9] string. I would like to know if it hacking attempts or search engines trying to index the site?

Thanks

Comment: @Sherif It's an example, obviously. `mysite.com` is not his actual domain. He's in South Africa and is not the CEO of United Online.

Comment: Post this here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: oh sorry! he means the request is in this form ... I do not think there is a browser that would append these numbers or "malfunction"

Comment: Do you have existing pages using this no-text[0-9] structure?

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input, will have a look at detecting user-agent and ip address to see if i can find the reason behind these requests.

Answer (score 2):

It could be an attempt to find security flaws. Many sites with a URL like `example.com/section/page` will blindly put `page` into a SQL query to select a page. A scrape program might try random input to see if any PHP errors (for example) came up.

Alternatively it could be polling to find the language used on the site, in order to try some common exploits for PHP, ASP etc.